# Continuing code in next line

Tags: c#, .net

```
if (some condition) || 
(some other condition)
{
   // do something
}
```

The above format does not work. Says `invalid expression "||"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if` statements in C# need to be entirely contained in a set of parentheses.  Add another set around  your two `||`ed expressions and that will work fine, even on two lines.

```
if ((some condition) ||
    (some other condition))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're missing outside parentheses on your `if` statement. e.g.

```
if ((some condition) || (some other condition))
{ 
   // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

your brackets are off, should be:

```
if ((some condition) || 
(some other condition))
{
   // do something
}
```